# Two columns per row for mobile version

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I want to place 3 cards per line for PC and 2 cards per line for mobile version of the site.
So I did

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6">
```

**Problem** I see only **one** card per line for mobile version.
You can test it https://edamer.ru

**Question**: How can I make 3 cards per line for PC and 2 cards per line for mobile version?

I found out that `width: 9rem` places two cards per line for mobile version (but makes awful PC version)

```
<div class="card" style="width: 9rem;">
```

How can I make **xs** class equals 9rem?

Comment: How can I improve my question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know which version of Bootstrap 4 you're using, but since Beta 2 changes, `col-xs-*` is gone, and it's replaced with just `col-*`.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/migration/#beta-2-changes, Grid System section.